# UIStatusBar won't disappear

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift2, uistatusbar

I've tried to create a class in Swift, which autohides my `UIStatusBar` and my `navigationController` after 1 Second.
My problem is, that the `StatusBar` is not going to disappear. This is what I got:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "prefersStatusBarHidden", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }

override func preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation() -> UIStatusBarAnimation {
    return UIStatusBarAnimation.Fade
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    if (barcounter == 0){
        hide()
        barcounter = 1
        return true
    }
    else {
        show()
        barcounter = 0
        return false
    }
}

@IBAction func picturePressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    prefersStatusBarHidden()
}

func hide(){

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 0.0

        }, completion: nil)

}

func show(){
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 1.0

        }, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override this method in whichever  view controller u want to hide uistatusbar.

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true;
}
```

if its not work then try this:-

```
In Info.plist set View controller-based status bar appearance to NO

And call UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = true
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: so the upper example I've already tried as you can see in my example..
Now I deleted it and tried the 2nd one. This one worked for me but not properly. At the moment the statusbar is hidden, but the navigationcontroller doesn't hide anymore

Comment: hey if its working then please approved the answer so that helpful to other

Comment: thank you. please correct the answer make it green so others can find easily.

Answer (score 0):

Alright.. I solved it like that:
I created a new class `HeaderAnimationHelper` in which I created the useable methods. Like that I can call it from everywhere.

So here you can see the Helper class:

import UIKit

```
class HeaderAnimationHelper {

    static let sharedInstance = HeaderAnimationHelper()
    var navi: UINavigationController!

    func hideController(var barcounter: Int, navigationController: UINavigationController) -> Int {
        navi = navigationController
        if (barcounter == 0){
            barcounter = 1
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation.Fade)
            hide()
        }
        else {
            show()
            barcounter = 0
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation.Fade)
        }
        return barcounter
    }

    func hide(){

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {

            self.navi.navigationBar.alpha = 0.0

            }, completion: nil)

    }

    func show(){
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {

            self.navi.navigationBar.alpha = 1.0

            }, completion: nil)

    }


}
```

and the next class is the main class in which you can put all you code and stuff... 
I created it like that:

```
import UIKit

class ContactMeViewController: UIViewController {


    var barcounter = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "animate", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }


    override func preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation() -> UIStatusBarAnimation {
        return UIStatusBarAnimation.Fade
    }

    @IBAction func picturePressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        animate()
    }

    func animate(){
        barcounter = HeaderAnimationHelper.sharedInstance.hideController(barcounter, navigationController: self.navigationController!)
    }

}
```

edit 10/07/15:

I've forgotten to mention, that it's important to add the dependency to the Info.plist

```
In Info.plist set View controller-based status bar appearance to NO
```

Watch out this method `UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation.Fade)`
       is depricated